# how can i import the csv file in wordpress woocommerce.?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, bulk-import, csv

my client has a Wordpress website and we are facing some issue while importing the products with variations in the website. the website link is https://www.primadonsanddonnas.com. The CSV file uploading some products variations not all and I have tried it with different plugins but couldn't figure it out. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Haroon,

In the past, I've used this paid extension through the WooCommerce store: https://woocommerce.com/products/product-csv-import-suite/

However, WooCommerce is in the process of phasing that plugin's functionality into their core release: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/

If the default core option does not yet meet your needs I would recommend checking out their paid extension.

One other tip: I would suggest setting up one product by hand, directly within WooCommerce. Export that option with the same sort of setup (built-in or plugin) you will use to import. Look closely at how it formats each product and format your import this way. Sometimes the documentation just doesn't explain how to format well. But if you look at something you've exported that is set up exactly the way you want it set up, your chances of a successful import go way up.